# Problema ao gerar build no Xamarin Android (No resource found that matches the given name "at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/icon')

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Sou um designer tentando aprender a montar telas para aplicativos Android através do Visual Studio, utilizando o Xamarin Android, então, bastante iniciante em termos técnicos relativos à area...

Comecei pelo básico, seguindo os tutoriais que o próprio Xamarin te dá, mas, basicamente, nenhum deles gera a build corretamente, sempre apresentando um erro aleatório. Neste caso específico, quero buscar solução para o problema que acontece neste tutorial: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/designer_overview/designer_walkthrough/

Já segui o passo-a-passo algumas vezes e ele sempre dá erro na hora da build. Desta última vez, o erro foi este:
(No resource found that matches the given name "at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/icon')

[image: Erro Xamarin Android]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei uma 'solução/gambiarra' que 'resolve' o problema:

Fui na MainActivity.cs e editei a linha 12 limpando a referência sobre o @mipmap/icon, deixando apenas assim:

```js
[Activity(Label = "DesignerWalkthrough", MainLauncher = true)]
```

A questão é: praticamente todos os tutoriais do próprio Xamarin contém algum pequeno problema assim que me impede de continuar testando. Neste caso específico,como eu poderia rodar a build sem precisar apagar a referência "Icon = "@mipmap/icon"?

UPDATE ------------>

Lendo um pouco mais, entendi que o erro está na referência da imagem do ícone. Eu havia lido num outro tópico que chamar os resources através do 'drawable' era antiquado e que o erro poderia estar ligado à isso: eu deveria alterar para o 'mipmap'. Entretanto, neste caso específico eu segui a linha inversa e troquei o mipmap para drawable na referência e o app rodou normalmente. Minha linha ficou assim:

```js
[Activity(Label = "DesignerWalkthrough", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/Icon")]
```